# Need to display different components based on whether a field is empty or not. Aura:If statement not working properly

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I need to Display a Certain Component Based on whether the item in my list has a field or not. I am trying to use != Null but right now it skips the first portion of the If statement regardless of if the field is null or not. Code and examples below:

the List seems to be read in properly:

Console Log:

> 0: {article: {…}}
>   1: {article: {…}}
>   2: {article: {…}}
>   3: {event: {…}}
>   4: {article: {…}}
>   5: {event: {…}}

Code for Aura:Iteration and Aura:If

```
   <aura:iteration items="{!v.listOfWrappers}" var="wrapper" end="10">          
    <aura:if isTrue="{!not(empty(wrapper.Event_Type_Filter__c))}"> 
        <section id="" class="container" onclick="">
            <div class="event-image" style="padding: 16px;"><img style="height: 100%;" src="{!$Resource.CalendarIcon}"/></div> 
            <div class="event-detail">
                <div class="event-title">{!wrapper.Name}</div>
                <div class="event-date">{!wrapper.StartDate__C}</div>
                <div class="event-location">{!wrapper.Location__C}</div>
                <div class="event-products">{!wrapper.Product_Filter__c}</div>
                <div class="event-type">{!wrapper.Event_Type_Filter__c}</div>
            </div>
        </section>
    <aura:set attribute="else">
        <section id="" class="container" onclick="">
            <div class="event-image" style="padding: 16px;"><img style="height: 100%;" src="{!$Resource.ArticleIcon}"/></div> 
            <div class="event-detail">
                <div class="article-title">{!wrapper.Title__c}</div>
                <div class="article-description">{!wrapper.Summary}</div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </aura:set>
    </aura:if> 
   </aura:iteration>
```

What is being displayed currently is only the else portion of the Aura:if. Furthermore the data for the item in the list is not being displayed either:

[image]

Comment: Continuation of: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/278095/need-to-get-a-list-from-my-apex-controller-to-display-with-auraiteration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data Display issue: My issue was that I was referencing a list comprised of two lists so instead of `{!wrapper.Name}` I needed `{!wrapper.event.Name}`

Aura:Iteration issue:

Once I realized the first part I was able to use `<aura:if isTrue="{!wrapper.event}">` to check which object type the next value in my list was, and then create the appropriate component to match.